# Error assigning data to table from DB?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to bind data from a database to a DataTable object but I keep receiving this error:

> The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

I believe this means there's an error coming from somewhere and being sent as a text\html.
However, if I bind the data using the sqldatasource tag in my aspx file to my grif it binds just fine fine.

Here's the function in my web service file:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public DataTable getTable()
    {
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable("AMR_COUNTY");

        ConnectionStringSettingsCollection s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wmoddevsql02.ePCR310_Server.dbo"].ToString()))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM AMR_COUNTY");
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                dataAdapter.Fill(myTable);
        }

        return myTable;

    }
}
```

and here's the call in my code-behind:

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (MCMwebservice.Service1SoapClient myWebService = new MCMwebservice.Service1SoapClient())
        {//use the session set userID to query Database for all incidents for the logged in user 
           dataTable = myWebService.getTable();
           WebDataGrid1.DataSource = dataTable;
            WebDataGrid1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

SOAP web services are intended to return XML, so you should embrace that and build the object from the XML representation of the data, like this:

```
public DataTable BuildDataTableFromXml()    
{
    StringReader theReader = new StringReader(xmlData);
    DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
    theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

    return theDataSet.Tables[0];
}
```

Note: SOAP is intended to be used by any client that can understand XML, so if you wanted to use this service from a Java client, then it would not understand what a `DataTable` is, because that is a .NET specific data structure.

Comment: thanks, figured out  i didn't have the connection string listed in the web services congif file